# regex extract/replace values from xml-like tags via named (sub)groups

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback, named, regex-group

Trying to create a simple text-translator in PHP.

It shoult match something like:

```
Bla bla {translator id="TEST" language="de"/}
```

The language can be optional

```
Blabla <translator id="TEST"/>
```

Here is the code:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback(
  '#{translator(\s+(?\'attribute\'\w+)="(?\'value\'\w+)")+/}#i',
  array($this, 'translateTextCallback'), 
  $aText
);
```

It extracts the "attributes", but fetches only the last one. My first thought was, it has to do with the group naming, when PHP overwrites the (named) array elements on every match. But leaving out the group naming it also only returns the last match.

Here is an array as returned to the callback as example

```
Array
(
    [0] => {translator id="TEST" language="de"/}
    [1] =>  language="de"
    [attribute] => language
    [2] => language
    [value] => de
    [3] => de
)
```

Comment: @void : Hello, and Welcome on StackOverflow ! I took the liberty to edit your post, to format the portions of code, so they are easier to read. For your next questions, this can be done using the icon with 0s and 1s on top of the edit box ; and, if needed, there is a link on the right of the "ask question" page, that points to the reference of the syntax you can use to write questions/answers :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate a group, you only get the last match.  There is no way around this.  You need to match the whole set of attribute/values and then parse them in code.